# SQL update Trigger issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-update

I have the following update trigger (code below) this is working, but not how I expected.
When I add info for the value VCODE namely V or AV within the Valve table, I get the following error (as the image below) [image: SQL Error] I know if I right click and execute the SQL the values are then populated, but I don't want to have to do this.
I've done a bit of digging around and I think it has something to do with the pkID, but I'm not sure what I need to do with the code to fix this problem. Would somebody please advise how I should rewrite the script below to avoid this error.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trValve] ON [dbo].[Valve]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Valve
    SET VSYS = 'VLV',
    SITE_CODE = '00123',
    VAREA = 'INL'
    FROM Valve t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.pkID = i.pkID
    WHERE i.VCODE = 'V'
    OR i.VCODE = 'AV'

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE VALVE
    SET ASSET_TAG = CONCAT (
            Valve.SITE_CODE,'-',Valve.VAREA,'-',valve.VSYS,'-',Cast(pkID AS VARCHAR(50))
            );
END
END
```

Comment: Sorry Image did not upload message reads;

Comment: This row was successfully committed to the database. However, a problem occurred when attempting to retrieve the data back after the commit. Because of this, the displayed data in the row is read-only. to fix this problem, please re-run the query

Comment: Curious that you `SET NOCOUNT ON` twice and update the `ASSET_TAG` for _every_ row in `VALVE`.

Comment: Does this have an impact on how the trigger functions? if so would you please explain. I'm making an asset tag for each valve based on the concatenated data they each will be individual ident for on site records

Comment: Also could this be the cause of my issues?